# Why does Arc<Mutex<T>> require T: Sync + Send?

Tags: rust

If I have a type that is not safe to send between threads, I wrap it with `Arc<Mutex<T>>`. This way I'm guaranteed that when I access it, I need to unlock it first. However, Rust still complains when `T` does not implement `Send + Sync`.

Shouldn't it work for any type? In my case, `T` is a struct that accesses a C object through FFI, so I cannot mark it as `Sync + Send`.

What can I do in this case and why won't Rust accept `Arc<Mutex<T>>` as safe to share between threads?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because you are the only one accessing something (at a time) does not mean it suddenly become okay to access things from different threads. It merely prevents *one* issue: data races. But there may be other issues with moving objects across threads.

For example it's common for low-level windowing APIs to only be able to be called from the main thread. Many low-level APIs are also only callable from the thread they were initialized in. If you wrap these APIs in Rust objects, you don't want these objects moving across threads *no matter what*.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Rust that `Arc<Mutex<MyType>>` is safe to share between threads without making the type itself `MyType` saf to share between threads?

Comment: in my case I just need to prevent data race

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Wrap it in a type and implement `Send` for that type manually. Of course this is you guaranteeing to the compiler that it is safe to `Send`, and if you are wrong about this you have lost safety.

Comment: do I really need to put it inside a struct? I can't just give a new name to the type `Arc<Mutex<MyType>>` and implement something for it?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Actually you should be able to write `impl Send for Arc<Mutex<MyType>> {}` directly.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs In the original you say that you can not mark the structure as Send, but… that's not true? As long as the type is under your control you can mark it as `Send`. Which simply means that the structure is not thread-bound (which some are). `Mutex<T>` is then `Sync` as long as `T: Send`.

Comment: @orlp it says `impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate` because `Arc` is not defined in the current crate for `impl Send for Arc<Mutex<SmolStack>> {}`

Answer (score 1):

The technical reason is the [`Mutex` implements `Sync` only if `T` is `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#impl-Sync-for-Mutex%3CT%3E).

And what helped me to see why `T` has to be `Send` is to think of thread local storage: Imagine the type involves some thread local variable, say a simple counter. Accessing it from different threads can result in reading different values, because each thread has its own instance. Therefore this type cannot be `Send`. And a `Mutex` must not make it `Sync`, because even with synchronized/exclusive access, seeing different values wouldn't be sound.

Going further, the property of being "pinned to a thread" can be transitive. Perhaps the type itself doesn't involve any thread local storage itself, but relies on some external low level APIs that does etc. I'd assume that as soon as there is some dependency on something this is specific to one particular thread, there is no amount of wrapping that can allow accessing it from different threads safely.