# How to wrap std::io::Write in Mutex for tracing-subscriber?

Tags: rust, thread-safety, rust-tracing

In the documentation for [Mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), it says that it implements `Send` and `Sync` -- which makes sense, because a `Mutex` is designed to be accessed from multiple threads that are locking, using the resource it protects, then unlocking.

However, in my code below, I get a compiler error that, as far as I can tell, complains that the Mutex doesn't implement Send/Sync:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::sync::Mutex;

use dotenvy::var;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tracing::Level;

struct MultiWriter {
    writers: Vec<Arc<dyn Write>>,
}

impl Write for MultiWriter {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        for writer in self.writers.iter_mut() {
            writer.write(buf)?;
        }
        Ok(buf.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        for writer in self.writers.iter_mut() {
            writer.flush()?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let mut writers: Vec<Arc<dyn Write>> = vec![(Arc::new(std::io::stderr()))];
    if let Some(log_file) = var("log_file").ok() {
        writers.push(Arc::new(File::create(log_file).unwrap()));
    }
    let mw = Mutex::new(MultiWriter { writers });

    let tsb = tracing_subscriber::FmtSubscriber::builder()
        .with_env_filter(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::from_default_env()).with_ansi(false)
        .with_writer(mw);

    if let Ok(log_level) = var("log_level") {
        match log_level.to_uppercase().as_str() {
            "TRACE" => tsb.with_max_level(Level::TRACE),
            "DEBUG" => tsb.with_max_level(Level::DEBUG),
            "INFO" => tsb.with_max_level(Level::INFO),
            "WARN" => tsb.with_max_level(Level::WARN),
            "ERROR" => tsb.with_max_level(Level::ERROR),
            _ => tsb.with_max_level(Level::INFO)
        }
        .try_init().expect("setting default subscriber failed");
    }   
}
```

```
error[E0599]: the method `try_init` exists for struct `SubscriberBuilder<DefaultFields, Format, tracing::level_filters::LevelFilter, std::sync::Mutex<MultiWriter>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:131:10
    |
131 |           .try_init().expect("setting default subscriber failed");
    |            ^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `SubscriberBuilder<DefaultFields, Format, tracing::level_filters::LevelFilter, std::sync::Mutex<MultiWriter>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /Users/sean/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tracing-subscriber-0.3.16/src/fmt/fmt_layer.rs:62:1
    |
62  | / pub struct Layer<
63  | |     S,
64  | |     N = format::DefaultFields,
65  | |     E = format::Format<format::Full>,
66  | |     W = fn() -> io::Stdout,
67  | | > {
    | | -
    | | |
    | |_doesn't satisfy `_: std::marker::Send`
    |   doesn't satisfy `_: std::marker::Sync`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `tracing_subscriber::fmt::Layer<Registry, DefaultFields, Format, std::sync::Mutex<MultiWriter>>: std::marker::Send`
            `tracing_subscriber::fmt::Layer<Registry, DefaultFields, Format, std::sync::Mutex<MultiWriter>>: std::marker::Sync`
```

If I remove the line `.with_writer(mw)` from my code below, the error goes away. Clearly the problem is related to the writer, but I'm not sure how to do this correctly.

The goal of the code is to write the logs from the `tracing` framework to both stderr and a file specified from [dotenvy](https://docs.rs/dotenvy/latest/dotenvy/) if a file name is specified (it's optional).

NB: I'm using the latest stable Rust and the released version of each crate used below, and compiling with std, libc, alloc, etc. (full Rust, not embedded) on MacOS, but the code is expected to work on the "multi-platform x86(_64) desktop" environment (Windows/MacOS/desktop Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the documentation for [Mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), it says that it implements Send and Sync

That's not completely true:

```
impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Send for Mutex<T>
impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Sync for Mutex<T>
```

This means that a Mutex is `Send` and `Sync` **only if `T` is `Send`** (the reason for this is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64779814/4674154).

However, T isn't `Send` here:

- `T` is a `struct MultiWriter`
- `struct MultiWriter` contains a `dyn Write`
- `dyn Write` is not `Send` (at least not always)
- in turn, `struct MultiWriter` isn't either.

To fix this, replace `dyn Write` by `dyn Write + Send`, and it should work.

Comment: It needs to be `dyn Write + Send + Sync`, because of the `Arc`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it needs to be emphasized that the OP is doing `Mutex<Arc<MyType>>` that this is different than `Arc<Mutex<MyType>>`.  If a type is `Send` and wrapped in a `Mutex`, the whole thing is `Send + Sync`, but since `Arc` needs both, that's important here.  But if `Mutex` is on the outside (like it is here) then `Arc` isn't satisfied by what's inside of it.

As Elias cites (correctly), `Mutex` only requires it's contained value to be `Send`, not both `Send + Sync`.  The OP's problem (one of them) is that `Mutex` is on the outside, and `Arc` demands both `Sync + Send` which `dyn Write` isn't.

[Arc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/sync.rs.html#249-252):

```rust
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Sync + Send> Send for Arc<T> {}
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Sync + Send> Sync for Arc<T> {}
```

[Mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/sync/mutex.rs.html#173-176):

```rust
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Send for Mutex<T> {}
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Sync for Mutex<T> {}
```

Ultimately @ChayimFriedman is right that for the OP's block of code, they need both (`dyn + Write + Send + Sync`), but I wanted to put down here even more as to *why*.